# Is it mutar to walk over the George Washington Bridge on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, geography, eruv-techumin

Is it mutar to walk over the George Washington Bridge on shabbos? In terms of techumin

Comment: Welcome Aaron and thanks for your interesting question.

Comment: Aaron, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Your question would be much stronger if you could [edit] in some more information about why you think this particular traversal would or would not be permitted.

Comment: If this applies to you personally, please [see a rabbi](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) for personal, practical advice. Or, as we like to say, CYLOR.

Answer (score 10):

According to Shmuely Wollenberger in [The Coffee Room at The Yeshiva World](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/techum-shabbosyom-tov-and-bridges) Rabbi Schachter held it was forbidden.

> Rav Schachter and his wife used to go for walks on Shabbos. They would
>   cross part of the George Washington bridge then stop and turn around
>   because the bridge is farther than the T'chum.

From Gershon Dubin at http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v37/mj_v37i55.html#CSN

> I know that the kehila in Washington Heights does not, per their
>   rabbonim's pesak decades ago, cross the GWB on Shabbos.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: I only know what I see.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I have never used the Coffee Room....those subtitles are from mods? ....I would've thought that each user chooses their own subtitles.